# What is a chalisa and what is the importance of chalisa?

Tags: gods, goddess

In Hindu dharma we have many gods and deity's and also we have different chalisas for them like Shiv Chalisa, Hanuman Chalisa and others.

My question is - what is a chalisa and what is its importance?

Why do we read it, what does it symbolize and why so many chalisas?

Answer (score 2):

We do worship of a God in many ways. The ways are formed like

- Mantrochar ( A statement or slogan repeated frequently ).
- Dhoon ( A Small Prayer sang repeatedly )
- Prayar ( Single time sang Prayer )
- Chalisa ( forty verse prayer )
- Dhyan ( Meditation )

[Source](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/) :

In Chalisa verses are praise and plead with devotion. The acts and deeds of deities are recalled in these verses to aid the devotee to meditate on righteous and noble qualities.

Hanuman Chalisa is very famous. Other known chalisa are listed below,

- [Ganesh Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/ganeshchalisa/ganchalisa.asp)
- [Durga Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/durgachalisa/durgachalisa.asp)
- [Ram Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/ramchalisa/ramchalisa.asp)
- [Shiv Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/shivchalisa/shivchalisa.asp)
- [Vindhaswari Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/vindhchalisa/vindhchalisa.asp)
- [Laxmi Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/laxmichalisa/laxmichalisa.asp)
- [Sai Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/Sai_chalisa/sai_chalisa.asp)
- [Shani Chailsa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/shanichalisa/shanichalisa.asp)
- [Gayatri Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/gayatrichalisa/gayatrichalisa.asp)
- [Krishna Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/krishnachalisa/krishnachalisa.asp)
- [Saraswati Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/saraschalisa/saraschalisa.asp)
- [Santoshi Mata Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/santoshichalisa/santoshichalisa.asp)
- [Bhairav Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/bhairavchalisa/bhairavchalisa.asp)
- [Ganga Chailsa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/gangachalisa/gangachalisa.asp)
- [Navagraha Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/navgraha_chalisa/navagraha_chalisa.asp)
- [Kali Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/Kali_chalisa/kali_chalisa.asp)
- [Radha Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/radha_chalisa/radhachalisa.asp)

Comment: thanks for the answer, however would also like to know about these points too.. `what is its importance, Why do we read it, what does it symbolize and why so many chalisas?` in a bit detail

Comment: you said its a `forty verse prayer` then what's the difference between this `forty verse prayer` and a normal prayer, why is it so important and why do we read it as compared to normal prayer..

Comment: Prayer is not some song it is feeling from heart @SidM Importance is given by individuals. `Chalisa` are Favorited because `Chalisa` involves that deity's life and his divine properties.

Answer (score 1):

Chalisa are 40 verses / sentences which describe or sungs as quality of devotees. there are hundreds of chalisa in Hinduism.. few of them listed below :

[Bhairav Chalisa](http://eng.mysticindia.info/bhairav-chalisa-lyrics-in-english/)
[Shiv Chalisa](http://eng.mysticindia.info/shiv-chalisa-lyrics-in-english-text/)
[Ganga Chalisa](http://eng.mysticindia.info/ganga-chalisa-lyrics-in-english/)
[Hanuman Chalisa Lyrics](http://eng.mysticindia.info/hanuman-chalisa-lyrics-in-english/)
[Gayatri Chalisa Lyrics](http://eng.mysticindia.info/gayatri-chalisa-lyrics-in-english/)

Answer (score 1):

**What is a chalisa and what is its importance**?

Chalisa is a collection of forty chaupaies in local language.They are primarily meant for common people who are devoted to God but are not able to recite or understand the meanings of the sanskrit hymns.

The first of these different chalishas was composed by Sri Tulsidasji.He compiled the now very famous 'Hanuman Chalisa'.According to the writer Sri Milan Kumar Gangopadhyay, the reason behind choosing the number of slokas as forty are

> 1. There is a Veda-mantra :  '*iyam samvaram parvateshu kshiyantam chatvarikshAm sahatah/anvavindata aujamAnAn authim jaghAnam dhanushayam sajjanAh sa* *indrah*', meaning that the monster named Samvar resided in a high cave surrounded by mountains. His torture on the sages was severe. Lord Indra killed him by throwing an arrow after a sruggle of FORTY days.So Tulsidasji took forty as a auspicious number.
> 2. Tulsidasji understood that the people in the age of kali will not have enough time to read lengthy hymns and so He limited it to forty lines.
> 3. The hymns are to purify our four aspects: manas, vuddhi, chitta and ahamkara.Each of these have ten aspects and so the total is forty.

**Why do we read it, what does it symbolize and why so many chalisas?**

Seeing the popularity of the Hanuman Chalisa, different chalishas were composed later by different devotees.We read it to praise the form of God we like. Tulsidasji has provided the 'falashruti' of reading the Hanuman Chalisha and later such falasrutis have been provided by all the writers of different chalishas.

As mentioned, different devotess like different forms and all are not able to recite or understand the meanings of the sanskrit hymns,So the Chalisas became popular. In the bhakti tradition, remembering and praising and praying to God is seen as extremely fruitful in gaining His or Her grace. As the Narada-Pancharatra reads

> Murkho vadati vishnaya dhiro vadati vishnave/samam mulyam yubhoyotsu bhavagrAhi janardanah, meaning the illiterate says 'vishnaya' and the learned says 'vishnave'.**To God both are the same as He accepts the Devotion.**

The introduction to 'Stavananjali' published by Nagpur Ramakrishna Math mentions tye importance of chantings of praises/stotras with proper understanding :

> stotras are part of vachik (vocal) puja (worship) called 'Bangmoyee puja' and should be chanted with correct chhanda and pronunciation and audible clear voice, **understanding the meanings of the stotras and contemplating on the 'bhava' (page 4-5).**

Reference: 1. The issue of Sri Hanuman Chalisa by Saptahik Bartaman, 8 December 2018.

2. Vishad Byakhya saha Hanuman Chalia, Milan kumar Gangopadhyay, Girija library

Answer (score 0):

Astrology often keeps talking about the planet Shani and his malefic effects on people’s lives. Shani is the custodian of justice and he is authority to disburse the results of good and bad to people. What we face in our lives are only the results of our doings in the past. However, chanting [Shani Chalisa](https://dharmyatra.org/shani-chalisa.php) can instill confidence in the heart and help remedy the miseries and challenges faced due to the horoscope afflicted by Shani.

Comment: Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)