# What is the significance of number 40 in forty verse prayer?

Tags: practice, prayer, numerology

Why the prayer contains 40 lines though 1, 11, 21 etc are considered as good in religious work?

Is there any significance of number 40 in hindu mythology ? Also which is the first Chalisa(forty verse) and who made it for whom?

FYI - I read this post but nothing there about the number 40.

[What is a chalisa and what is the importance of chalisa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2510/what-is-a-chalisa-and-what-is-importance-of-chalisa)