# What gives the "spiritual - theological authenticity" to modern compositions like Chālīsās & ārtís?

Tags: scripture, belief, bhakti, hymn, hanuman-chalisa

*Hanumāna Chālīsā* is by far, one of the most popular devotional hymn to a God. It's authorship is credited to *Tulsídāsa*, although few other [sources](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=FdtnCZsVZbEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lutgendorf%20philip%20chalisa%20bp%20singh%20singh%20in%201994&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipjPTc7cjvAhUmyzgGHQ4rDOwQ6AEwA3oECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=Bp%20singh%20in%201994&f=false) might also call it as a later interpolated addition (by some followers of *Tulsídāsa*), to the original authored works by *Tulsídāsa*.

Anyway, almost all major deities in the present popular hindu culture have a separate *[Chālisā](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2510/what-is-a-chalisa-and-what-is-the-importance-of-chalisa?r=SearchResults)* devoted to them? Some of these deities  are - *Surya, Gayatri, Shiva, Durga, Vishnu, Ganesha, Shani*, et al.

So, my question is, who are these authors of  various *Chālīsās*? I mean, obviously each Chālīsā generally mention its authors' name in either the penultimate or the final couplets of the respective Chālīsā. So, are these authors to considered, exalted devotees or personalities, just like we attribute it to *Tulsídāsa*?

For example:- *Tulsídāsa* is considered an exalted devotee of the Lord and it is from this devotion of his perhaps, the *Hanumāna Chālīsā* is attributed with so much of credibility and authority as a sacred hymn.

**But, what about all the other *Chālīsās*? What drives their prowess as an authoritative & effective composition hymn?**

**How might one, decide on the *"Spiritual - Theological authenticity"* of any of these devotional compositions?**

One reason that maybe assigned is that, it's *Bhakti* and faith of the compiler, which gives them the credibility and the power for its effectiveness in alleviating *dukha* in its various forms, and thus, its considered befitting for us normal humans to recite them.

But, I'm more of looking for some specific scriptural (or from relevant *acharyas*) inferences or injunctions, which say something on the credibility of these kind of "new or neo-authors"  based compositions, as effective hymns in alleviating the problems of the devotee.

**Can all these recent compositions (like *Chālīsās*, *ārtís*, etc) be considered on a par level with the  eternal *Vedic* hymns or the ancient *Paurāṇika Stotras*?**

---

Specific  references from the scriptures and relevant - competent *gurus*, *acharyas* or known commentators will be much appreciated.

Comment: Durga Chalisa ends with "Deviidaasa Sharanna Nija Jaanii |" which means the author is someone named Devidasa. https://greenmesg.org/stotras/durga/durga_chalisa.php

Comment: The author of Shiva Chalisa is someone named Ayoddha Das. You can find it at the end of the Chalisa.

Comment: @Rickross that I have already mentioned in my question itself, I know, where all authors are mentioned in these composition, question  Is a bit different

Comment: I thought you're asking about who the authors are for Chalisas other than Hanuman Chalisa and you know the author for Hanuman Chalisa.

Comment: I posted my comments upon seeing the title the question had "Who are the authors of the other Chālīsās, besides the Hanumāna Chālīsā?" May be you already them by names but wanted more info about them.

Comment: Interesting question. I think they are effective but can't be equated to Vedic Slokas/Mantras.

Comment: Lol it was too long... I just read the title from which I could not have guessed that you know the various authors names already.@Vivikta

Comment: @Rickross, yeah, the title was very misleading, so I changed it too for better understanding ;)

Comment: @RishX, yes that's my guess too. Let's see, if some Interesting answer come up. ;))

Comment: Yes that's good @Vivikta

Comment: I was thinking of asking this question, you beat me to it :D

Comment: @Surya, lol. maybe you can try answering it then. Then you beat me there. ;) :P

Comment: @Vivikta lol if I knew the answer I wouldn't have had the question :P Let's see if someone has an insight on this